# Formulating deterministic and stochastic production models (not solving them) [Beginner's Operations Class]

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, linear-programming, operations-research

[Question provided in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS501.jpg)

This question has been troubling me as I am not used to questions without numbers as it is hard for me to visualise. I also find stochastic problems hard in general.

So far what I have come up with for part a):

Could I let xi = amount produced at plant i, tij = amount sent from plant i to retailer j

minimise: xi*P+ti*cij

1)  Production should not be exceeded plant capacity: xi<=Bi

2)  Amount sent from each plant can not exceed amount produced tij<=xi

3)  Amount sent to each retailer should not exceed average demand tij
<= average dj

4) Non- negativity >=0

For the part b I am at a loss at how to develop the stochastic model. I know the first stage decision variables are to choose the amount to produce, and at the second stage when demands are known the variables are the amount to transport.

I would be extremely grateful for any hints for this question (or these types of questions in general). Thanks!

Comment: If you work with inequalities the a retailer has to receive **at least** $d_j$, not at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would work with more equalities rather than inequalities. Beside that for the second and third constraint we have to sum up the amounts to be sent.

$\sum_{j=1}^R t_{ij}=x_i \ \ \forall \ i \in \{1,\ldots, P \}$

$\sum_{i=1}^P t_{ij}=d_j \ \ \forall \ j \in \{1,\ldots, R \}$

Comment: Thank you for replying! I think I understand now.